# Hola tengo un problema con las listas de python

Tags: python

Al momento de agregar otra lista no me deja ejecutarlo, no puedo guardar el peso y la altura en LISTA, como hago para guardarlos, o como haria para guardarlos en otra parte sino.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import os
animal = []
lista = []
zoologico = {}
aracnidos = 0
mamiferos = 0
aves = 0
reptiles = 0
anfibios = 0
peces = 0
tunicados = 0
equinodermos = 0
celentereos = 0
poriferos = 0
platelmintos = 0
nematodos = 0
moluscos = 0
anelidos = 0
crustaceos = 0
insectos = 0
mariapodos = 0


def menu():
    os.system("cls") 
    print "Selecciona una opción"
    print "\t1 - Ingresar nuevos animales"
    print "\t2 - ver cada uno de los animales en el zoologico"
    print "\t3 - ver la cantidad de animales en el zoologico"
    print "\t4 - ver la cantidad de animales por reino"
    print "\t9 - salir"


while True:
    menu()
    opcionMenu = input("Que opcion desea elegir >> ")


if opcionMenu == 1:
    ani = raw_input("ingrese un animal: ")
    altura = raw_input("ingrese la altura del animal a ingresar: ")
    peso = raw_input("Ingrese el peso del animal a ingresar: ")
    animal.append(ani)
    lista.append(peso,altura)

    def menu2():
        os.system("cls")
        print "A que reino pertenece:"
        print "\t1 - aracnidos"
        print "\t2 - mamiferos"
        print "\t3 - aves"
        print "\t4 - reptiles"
        print "\t5 - anfibios"
        print "\t6 - peces"
        print "\t7 - tunicados"
        print "\t8 - equinodermos"
        print "\t9 - celentereos"
        print "\t10 - poriferos"
        print "\t11 - platelmintos"
        print "\t12 - nematodos"
        print "\t13 - moluscos"
        print "\t14 - anelidos"
        print "\t15 - crustaceos"
        print "\t16 - insectos"
        print "\t17 - mariapodos"

    while True:
        menu2()
        opcionMenu2 = input("Por favor elija un reino >> ")
        if opcionMenu2 == 1:
            aracnidos = aracnidos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 2:
            mamiferos = mamiferos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 3:
            aves = aves + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 4:
            reptiles = reptiles + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 5:
            anfibios = anfibios + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 6:
            peces = peces + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 7:
            tunicados = tunicados + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 8:
            equinodermos = equinodermos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 9:
            celentereos = celentereos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 10:
            poriferos = poriferos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 11:
            platelmintos = platelmintos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 12:
            nematodos = nematodos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 13:
            moluscos = moluscos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 14:
            anelidos = anelidos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 15:
            crustaceos = crustaceos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 16:
            insectos = insectos + 1
            break
        if opcionMenu2 == 17:
            mariapodos = mariapodos + 1
            break

elif opcionMenu == 2:
    for a in zip(animal):
        print a
    print "Pulse enter para continuar"
    raw_input()

elif opcionMenu == 3:
    cantidad = len(animal)
    print "total de animales actualmente en el zoologico: ",cantidad
    print "Pulse enter para continuar"
    raw_input()

elif opcionMenu == 4:
    print "En el reino de los aracnidos hay",aracnidos, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los mamiferos hay",mamiferos, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los aves hay",aves, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los reptiles hay",reptiles, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los anfibios hay",anfibios, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los peces hay",peces, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los tunicados hay",tunicados, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los equinodermos hay",equinodermos, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los celentereos hay",celentereos, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los poriferos hay",poriferos, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los platelmintos hay",platelmintos, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los nematodos hay",nematodos, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los moluscos hay",moluscos, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los anelidos hay",anelidos, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los crustaceos hay",crustaceos, "animales"
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los insectos hay",insectos, "animales" 
    print ""
    print "En el reino de los mariapodos hay",mariapodos, "animales"
    print ""
    print "Pulse enter para continuar"
    raw_input()
```

Comment: Puedes salvar los dos datos como una tupla `lista.append((peso,altura))`

Answer (score 0):

Intuyo que tu problema está en

```
lista.append(peso,altura)
```

Esto no se puede hacer. O guardas los elementos en diferentes listas, (una lista para el peso y otra para la altura), o, juntas esos dos valores de alguna manera y ya podrías meterles dentro de tu lista.